# After any Composer command, does Composer or core set (or harden) the file permissions?

Tags: security

After any Composer command (for example, `composer create-project`, `composer require`, and `composer update`), does Composer or Drupal set (or harden) the file permissions?

Comment: We can answer one question at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The [system_requirements](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/9.5.x/core/modules/system/system.install#L35) function of Drupal hardens the permissions of files *and the directories containing the files*. It is nothing to do with Composer commands.